# InteliJ and Scene Builder Intergration failed

Tags: java, javafx

Failed to open the file in Scene Builder

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.fxml.LoadListener 
PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, 192.5728.98] 
com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@7f21125e


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class 
com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader: 
com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener [Plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX]
```

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with 2019.2 being bundled with Jetbrains' own JDK (JBR) in version 11 by default now. You can manually download a version with JBR8 (as long as they support it) or install the Oracle JDK8 and use the version without JBR. Link is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html

Another possibility is to download the standalone Scene Builder and open the file every time via right click in IntelliJ (quite annoying).

Via Google you can find that they have the issue in their bug tracker (multiple times): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209562 for 4 month.

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction - thanks. You can use the "switch Boot JDK" and point it to your JDK without having to reinstall Idea.

Answer (score 1):

I got same, and fixed.
(I dont know what makes the error)

I guess you updated intelliJ IDEA to
`2019.2 (192.5728.98)`
then the error caused.

And the Stable version (actually `RC`) is
`2019.1.4 (191.8026.36)`
This version didn't cause the error (for now)

> If you just want to use the IDE,
>   using Stable (or RC) Version is easy fix for it.

Comment: I downgraded my INTELIJ  and that problem was fixed thanks